# Digital Circuit for Truth Table

Tags: digital-logic

I am trying to determine a circuit that will produce an output (W, X, Y, Z) given an input (A, B) based on the following truth table:

[image]

What would be the simplest way to accomplish this? I was thinking about starting with a 2-4 decoder and add some digital gates, but would like to avoid too many parts. The point of this was to use 2 I/O pins instead of 4, but perhaps it is not worth it.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want a discrete logic solution (not, for example, how you would do this in an FPGA)?

Comment: Discrete logic is needed, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First simplifications

We notice that, whenever \$A\$ is set, \$W\$ is too, so the formula for \$W\$ will look something like \$A +XXX \$. Same goes for \$B\$ and \$Z\$. \$B\$ and \$X\$ too have this property

### Taking it from there

We further notice that, \$W\$ is linked to \$A\$ in an even stronger way (and same goes for \$B\$ and \$X\$). We have $$W = A$$ and $$X = B$$
\$Z\$ however, has a "special case". Even when \$B\$ isn't set, if \$A\$ isn't as well, \$Z\$ is set. So we need a signal that is \$1\$ if and only if \$A = 0\$ and \$B = 0\$. This is a NOR gate. So :
$$Z = B + \overline{A + B}$$
\$Y\$ is set if and only if \$A\$ and \$B\$ are set. This is the definition of an AND gate. Thus :
$$Y = A\cdot B$$

### Optimizing for less chips

From DeMorgan's law, we have $$\overline{A + B} \Rightarrow \overline{A} \cdot \overline{B}$$

Thus, as a recap, we see that :
$$W = A$$
$$X = B$$
$$Y = A\cdot B$$
$$Z = B + \overline{A} \cdot \overline{B}$$
We need two AND gates, two NOT gates and an OR gate. As gates of similar types are often packaged by 2, 4 or 6, you should be able to get away with 3 packages.

Comment: Z can be simplified further.

Comment: This process helps, thank you. With `W` and `X` I can wire it up in parallel with `A` and `B`, so that leaves me with an ANDN gate for `Y` and a NOR + OR combination for `Z`.

Comment: I personally do not see how, at least in an motivated way (other than "just" building the truth table). I you'd like to edit my answer, I can make it a Community Wiki.

Comment: I didn't want to just hand the answer to OP (it's better for them if they have to think a bit) but, Z = B + ~A. If you're using DIP packages it may not make a difference, but if you're using SMT 1-gate packages, it saves a couple packages.

Comment: I understand your method, and will probably apply it in the future. I will *maybe* edit with a motivated explanation, if I find one. At worst, there will still be your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Think about each output as a separate problem, and you'll find it much easier.

W, X, and Y can be solved with 1 (or fewer, depending on your fan-out requirement) gate each. Once you see them, these solutions are trivial.

Z needs 2 gates.